# Pyomo not building model correctly

Tags: mathematical-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, pyomo

Long time operations research guy, first time Pyomo user.  I'm building out a nonlinear program as a research project and trying it in Pyomo.  Since this is in proof of concept phase, I'm just hard-coding all the variables, constraints and objective function.  All's apparently good until I send it to NEOS:

```
solver_manager = SolverManagerFactory('neos')
results = solver_manager.solve(model, opt=SolverFactory('couenne'))
results.write()
```

Clearly NEOS isn't getting the full model build: results says that it has 92 variables (should be 108) and zero constraints.

```
results.write()
# ==========================================================
# = Solver Results                                         =
# ==========================================================
# ----------------------------------------------------------
#   Problem Information
# ----------------------------------------------------------
Problem: 
- Lower bound: -inf
  Upper bound: inf
  Number of objectives: 1
  Number of constraints: 0
  Number of variables: 92
  Sense: unknown
# ----------------------------------------------------------
#   Solver Information
# ----------------------------------------------------------
Solver: 
- Status: ok
  Message: couenne\x3a Optimal
  Termination condition: optimal
  Id: 3
# ----------------------------------------------------------
#   Solution Information
# ----------------------------------------------------------
Solution: 
- number of solutions: 0
  number of solutions displayed: 0
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong here in defining or passing arguments to NEOS?

Comment: Could you double check the size of your model before sending it to the solver? You can use the `build_model_size_report` utility function to do this. Import it using: `from pyomo.util.model_size import build_model_size_report`, build the report by passing your model `report = build_model_size_report(model)`, and look at the activated variables and constraints: `report.activated.variables` and `report.activated.constraints`.

Comment: Looks right:  ` ModelSizeReport(activated = Container(binary_variables = 0, constraints = 14, continuous_variables = 0, disjunctions = 0, disjuncts = 0, integer_variables = 76, nonlinear_constraints = 2, variables = 76), overall = Container(binary_variables = 0, constraints = 14, continuous_variables = 0, disjunctions = 0, disjuncts = 0, integer_variables = 108, nonlinear_constraints = 2, variables = 108), warning = Container(unassociated_disjuncts = 0)) `

Comment: New info: `WARNING: Failed to create solver with name 'couenne': Failed to set executable
    for solver asl. File with name=couenne either does not exist or it is not
    executable. To skip this validation, call set_executable with
    validate=False.  `  Do I need an executable locally since I'm sending it to neos?

Comment: If you compare the number of `activated` variables to the number of `overall` variables it looks like you have defined some variables that do not appear in any constraints which may be part of the issue you're seeing. Try printing your model using `model.pprint()` and verifying that the constraints are what you expect. You shouldn't need a solver executable if you're using neos.

Comment: I have a set of 32 "variables" that have bounds defined that make them constant, and they aren't used in any constraints, just in the objective function, so I can hard-code them into the objective function and remove those variables. I'll do what you suggested a little later.  Thing is, the constraints are all linear and the decision variables are all continuous or integer, but the objective function is nonlinear so that's why I'm trying to use NEOS with couenne.

Comment: This looks like it might be a bug in generating/writing the results object. If I run couenne locally the solver log indicates the expected number of constraints/variables but when I run `results.write()` it prints 0 constraints and the correct number of variables. I think the optimal solution is still being returned and loaded back into the model correctly, there is just a minor bug in generating the results object (on the Pyomo side, not the solver side).